# Hanvon FaceID result String Parsing

Tags: regex, xml, json, parsing

I need little help in string parsing... Here's he result string from FaceID:

```
Return(result=\"success\" dev_id=\"6714113100001517\" total=\"24\"\r\n
time=\"2014-06-16 17:56:44\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"0\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-06-16 17:57:45\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"0\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-06-16 17:57:58\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"2\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-06-16 17:58:02\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"1\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-06-16 17:58:04\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"0\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-06-16 17:58:19\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"2\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-11-29 13:23:36\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"0\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-11-29 13:23:46\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"2\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n
time=\"2014-11-29 13:23:49\" id=\"399\" name=\"\" workcode=\"0\"
status=\"0\" authority=\"0X55\" card_src=\"from_check\"\r\n)
```

I know how to loop through the string and matching tokens, but I wonder if there could be any regex for this type of string? Or maybe if it's easy to convert it to XML or JSON? If so, what will be better in performance?

I want separate values for Time, ID, Name, Workcode, status, authority, card_src — for example a list or collection of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate the values you can use:

```
\b(time|id|name|workcode|status|authority|card_src)=\\"(.*?)\\"
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rW5xC8/1)

---

In capturing group 1 you get the name.
In capturing group 2 you get the value.

Answer (score 0):

sure - you could do a regex like:

```
time=\\"([^\\]+)\\" id=\\"([^\\]+)\\" name=\\"([^\\]+)\\" workcode=\\"([^\\]+)\\" status=\\"([^\\]+)\\" authority=\\"([^\\]+)\\" card_src=\\"([^\\]+)\\"
```

And then loop through the groups within each match to see the matched values (which would be language specific code)

In the regex above
 `\\` represents a `\` (backslashes have to be escaped)
 `( )` represents a capturing group (so the captured value can be referenced in the result
 `[^\\]+` means a class of characters that are *not* a `\` repeated one or more times

This is an example of c# code looping through the matches to extract the captured values:

```
var input = "your input string... cant be bothered to repeat it here!";
var pattern= @"time=\\""([^\\]+)\\"" id=\\""([^\\]+)\\"" name=\\""([^\\]+)\\"" workcode=\\""([^\\]+)\\"" status=\\""([^\\]+)\\"" authority=\\""([^\\]+)\\"" card_src=\\""([^\\]+)\\""";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine("time is: {0}", match.Groups[1]);
   Console.WriteLine("id is: {0}", match.Groups[2]);
   Console.WriteLine("name is: {0}", match.Groups[3]);
   // and so on...
}
```